# Scala function variable: use default values (from function or define in variable definition)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have defined a method that used a default variable.
When calling the method with or without a value for this variable, everything works as expected.

However, when i assign the method to a function variable, it is not possible to call it without the parameter anymore.

This example illustrates the behavior:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    doStuff(5)
    doStuff()
    val f : (Int => Unit) = doStuff
    f(5)
    f()  //compiler error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: Int)Unit in trait Function1. Unspecified value parameter v1.
  }

  def doStuff(x : Int = 5) : Unit = {
    println(x)
  }
```

However, I would need this for a more coplex example. Can I get my function variable to use the default value of the function `doStuff`? Do I have to use another type for the function variable?

Alternatively, can i define a separate default variable for the function variable `f`?

Comment: `doStuff` is not a function, it is a method, which is a completely different thing. `f` is a function. One of the differences between methods and functions is that methods can have optional parameters with default values and functions can't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok, so it is not possible to achieve what I want? I guess the terminology confuses more people, since "default values" for functions are mentioned in some tutorials. Would you use your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

In your f function where you are defining your anonymous function, where are you giving a default value for the Int argument that you are passing? What happens is that the compiler would provide you an apply method and this apply method is taking in a non default Int as an argument!

You could probably expand your anonymous function as:

```
  val func1 = new Function1[Int, Unit] {
    def apply(x: Int = 5) = println(x)
  }
```

But even that would result in a compilation failure as the default values does not get applied for the Function1 trait!

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably what you want:

```
  val f = new Function1[Int, Unit] {
    def apply(x: Int) = doStuff(x)
    def apply() = doStuff()
  }
```